# Decompose to BCNF

Tags: database, decomposition

I just need to check if I got 'decomposition' to BCNF properly.

I've got

```
R (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

FD's:

```
F -> E,B
F -> A
C -> D
A -> G
```

I found **(F,C)** as a KEY
And after decomposition I've got the following relations:

```
R1 (C,D)
R2 (A,G)
R3 (A,B,C,E,F)
```

Can someone have a look? Much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`R3 (A,B,C,E,F)` should be decomposed to:

```
R4 (A,B,E,F)
R5 (F,C)
```

This is because `F -> E,B and F -> A` are the two FDs that violate BCNF for `R3 (A,B,C,E,F)`. So you have to decompose `R3` into `R4` and `R5`.

For `R4` I took `F+` and for `{R5}` I took `{R3 - Dependents of F+}` by following the decomposition rule for BCNF. Dependents of `F+` are `A,B,E`.